# Personal statement vs letter of intent

Tags: statement-of-purpose

I am applying to PhD programs in different universities and while for some universities it is asked that I write a personal statement (PS), for other universities I have to write a letter of intent (LoI). I have already written a personal statement. My problem is that I do not know whether or not there is a difference between PS and LoI (some websites state that both are similar while some other ones state the opposite).

So are PS and LoI the same thing or not ?

Comment: It depends on their content. Read on what the schools want.

Comment: In my case, it is a PhD position published on INSPIRE hep and where the only sentence related to "letter of intent" is : "Application material should include cv, a letter of intent, and university grades (undergraduate and master), and the name of three academic personnel who agreed to write reference letters upon our request." Therefore there is no specific information about the letter of intent.

Comment: Then they're equivalent modulo specific schools' requirements.